# .text() wont replace text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace my text for the quantity but whenever I run the function it will log everything it needs to but then say undefined. Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```js
function UnHide() { // Un-hide item when added to cart
  var obj = {
    "BackGlassCheckout": Cookies.get('BackGlassCheckout'),
    "BackCameraCheckout": Cookies.get('BackCameraCheckout'),
    "BatteryCheckout": Cookies.get('BatteryCheckout'),
    "ChargingPortCheckout": Cookies.get('ChargingPortCheckout'),
    "FrontCameraCheckout": Cookies.get('FrontCameraCheckout'),
    "GlassCameraCoverCheckout": Cookies.get('GlassCameraCoverCheckout'),
    "LogicBoardCheckout": Cookies.get('LogicBoardCheckout'),
    "ScreenCheckout": Cookies.get('ScreenCheckout')
  };
  $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
    if (value == 1) {
      $('#' + key).removeClass("hidden");
    }
    console.log(key, value);
  });
  QuantityCheckout();
}


function QuantityCheckout () {
  var obj = {
    "BackGlassQty": Cookies.get('BackGlassQty'),
    "BackCameraQty": Cookies.get('BackCameraQty'),
    "BatteryQty": Cookies.get('BatteryQty'),
    "ChargingPortQty": Cookies.get('ChargingPortQty'),
    "FrontCameraQty": Cookies.get('FrontCameraQty'),
    "GlassCameraCoverQty": Cookies.get('GlassCameraCoverQty'),
    "LogicBoardQty": Cookies.get('LogicBoardQty'),
    "ScreenQty": Cookies.get('ScreenQty')
  };
  $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
    var test = '#' + key.replace('Qty', '') + 'Quantity'
    console.log(test , value);
    $('#' + key.replace('Qty', '') + 'Quantity').text('test');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="javascript:UnHide()">
  <div id="AllItemsCheckout">
    <table>
      <tr id="BackGlassCheckout" class="hidden">
        <td><img class="BuyItemImg" src="images/BackGlass.jpg" alt="Back Glass" width="379" height="450"></td>
        <td class="CheckoutCostAndButton">
          <h1>Back Glass</h1>
          <p class="BackGlassQuantity">I WANT TO REPLACE THIS</p>
          <p class="Price">Cost: $16.99</p>
          <a href="#" id="BackGlass" onclick="RemoveFromCart(this.id)" class="RemoveFromCart">Remove From Cart</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Well, you've got `<body onload="javascript:UnHide()">`, so where is the `UnHide` function? Next, where is the call for `QuantityCheckout`, which is what you are asking about? And, by the way `javascript:` is unnecessary.

Comment: I added it i also use js cookies so the cookies may not work. @ScottMarcus

Comment: $('#' + key.replace('Qty', '') + 'Quantity').text('test'), Here replace '#' with '. ' You are trying to get element by class , for class you need use '.' and not '#'.Bellow is the syntax:$('.' + key.replace('Qty', '') + 'Quantity').text('test')

Comment: you have html elements with class and you are trying to replace using id `selector (#)`, use class `selector (.)` like `$('.' + key.replace('Qty', '') + 'Quantity')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the following changes to the QuantityCheckout function.

```
$.each(obj, function (key, value) {
  var test = '.' + key.replace('Qty', '') + 'Quantity'
  console.log(test , value);
  $('.' + key.replace('Qty', '') + 'Quantity').text('test');
});
```

Note: Your use of Cookies makes it very difficult for us to run the code and test our possible solution. Please find some other way of doing the same thing. :D